# How to work female and male counts I got error

Tags: pandas, numpy, count, shapes

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r'file.xlsx', header=0, skipfooter=1)
print(data)
numpy_array = data.to_numpy()

female_counts = data[data['Gender'] == 'Female'].shape[0]
male_counts = data[data['Gender'] == 'Male'].shape[0]

smoked_counts = data[data['SMOKING\nCONDITION'] == 'Smoked'].shape[0]
not_smoked_counts = data[data['SMOKING\nCONDITION'] == 'Not Smoked'].shape[0]

print("Female Counts:", female_counts)
print("Male Counts:", male_counts)
print("Smoked Counts:", smoked_counts)
print("Not Smoked Counts:", not_smoked_counts)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the error özlem?

Comment: can you please share output of print(data) so it will be easy to understand structure of data.

Comment: Could you share the dataset (or a subset of it)? Alternatively, reporting the output of the _print_ as suggested by @root_coding would be fine as well.